# Extract value from response and use it in next sampler request body specific

Tags: jmeter-5.0

How to extract an id like `5105800`, `5105801`, `5105802` and his quantity `200`, `50` , `40` from response Body and reuse it in the request body as show below?

Response Body:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "callOrders": [
            {
                "promotionId": null,
                "Promotion": null,
                "Lines": [
                    {
                        "id": 5105800,
                        "quantity": 200,
                        "skuId": 85,
                        "callId": 494281,
                        "skuBatchId": 587,
                        "amountDetails": {
                            "rate": 144.22,
                            "grossAmount": 32593.72,
                            "netAmount": 32593.72,
                            "taxAmount": 3749.72,
                            "taxableAmount": 28844,
                            "subTotal": 28844,
                            "billDiscount": 0,
                            "tradeDiscount": 0,
                            "discountAmount": 0,
                            "promotionDiscount": 0,
                            "topUpDiscount": 0,
                            "__typename": "AmountDetail"
                        },
                        "rateDetails": {
                            "rlp": 144.22,
                            "rlpWithVat": 162.9686,
                            "netPrice": 144.22,
                            "netPriceWithVat": 162.9686,
                            "__typename": "RateDetail"
                        },
                        "SKU": {
                            "id": 85,
                            "title": "Ariel Oxyblu 500 gm x 48 [82262305]",
                            "__typename": "SKU"
                        },
                        "SKUBatch": {
                            "priceDetails": {
                                "rlp": 144.22,
                                "dlp": 137.35,
                                "vatPercentage": 0.13,
                                "mrpSrp": 176,
                                "mrpStatus": true,
                                "__typename": "SKUPrice"
                            },
                            "batchDetails": {
                                "batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
                                "__typename": "SKUBatch"
                            },
                            "usageDate": {
                                "manufacture": "0000-00-00",
                                "expiry": "0000-00-00",
                                "__typename": "SKUUsage"
                            },
                            "updatedAt": "2018-12-01",
                            "active": true,
                            "__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
                        },
                        "Promotion": {
                            "id": null,
                            "title": null,
                            "type": null,
                            "scope": null,
                            "criteria": null,
                            "__typename": "Promotion"
                        },
                        "promotionId": null,
                        "distributorId": 16,
                        "__typename": "Line",
                        "inStock": "INSTOCK",
                        "freeSku": false,
                        "focusedSku": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5105801,
                        "quantity": 50,
                        "skuId": 82,
                        "callId": 494281,
                        "skuBatchId": 551,
                        "amountDetails": {
                            "rate": 281.88,
                            "grossAmount": 15926.22,
                            "netAmount": 15926.22,
                            "taxAmount": 1832.22,
                            "taxableAmount": 14094,
                            "subTotal": 14094,
                            "billDiscount": 0,
                            "tradeDiscount": 0,
                            "discountAmount": 0,
                            "promotionDiscount": 0,
                            "topUpDiscount": 0,
                            "__typename": "AmountDetail"
                        },
                        "rateDetails": {
                            "rlp": 281.88,
                            "rlpWithVat": 318.5244,
                            "netPrice": 281.88,
                            "netPriceWithVat": 318.5244,
                            "__typename": "RateDetail"
                        },
                        "SKU": {
                            "id": 82,
                            "title": "Ariel Oxyblu 1 kg x 24 [82250306]",
                            "__typename": "SKU"
                        },
                        "SKUBatch": {
                            "priceDetails": {
                                "rlp": 281.88,
                                "dlp": 268.45,
                                "vatPercentage": 0.13,
                                "mrpSrp": 344,
                                "mrpStatus": true,
                                "__typename": "SKUPrice"
                            },
                            "batchDetails": {
                                "batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
                                "__typename": "SKUBatch"
                            },
                            "usageDate": {
                                "manufacture": "0000-00-00",
                                "expiry": "0000-00-00",
                                "__typename": "SKUUsage"
                            },
                            "updatedAt": "2018-01-31",
                            "active": true,
                            "__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
                        },
                        "Promotion": {
                            "id": null,
                            "title": null,
                            "type": null,
                            "scope": null,
                            "criteria": null,
                            "__typename": "Promotion"
                        },
                        "promotionId": null,
                        "distributorId": 16,
                        "__typename": "Line",
                        "inStock": "INSTOCK",
                        "freeSku": false,
                        "focusedSku": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5105802,
                        "quantity": 40,
                        "skuId": 769,
                        "callId": 494281,
                        "skuBatchId": 733,
                        "amountDetails": {
                            "rate": 197.53,
                            "grossAmount": 8928.356,
                            "netAmount": 8928.356,
                            "taxAmount": 1027.156,
                            "taxableAmount": 7901.2,
                            "subTotal": 7901.2,
                            "billDiscount": 0,
                            "tradeDiscount": 0,
                            "discountAmount": 0,
                            "promotionDiscount": 0,
                            "topUpDiscount": 0,
                            "__typename": "AmountDetail"
                        },
                        "rateDetails": {
                            "rlp": 197.53,
                            "rlpWithVat": 223.2089,
                            "netPrice": 197.53,
                            "netPriceWithVat": 223.2089,
                            "__typename": "RateDetail"
                        },
                        "SKU": {
                            "id": 769,
                            "title": "H&S 2in1 Active Protect 180 ml x 24 [82302894]",
                            "__typename": "SKU"
                        },
                        "SKUBatch": {
                            "priceDetails": {
                                "rlp": 197.53,
                                "dlp": 186.35,
                                "vatPercentage": 0.13,
                                "mrpSrp": 250,
                                "mrpStatus": true,
                                "__typename": "SKUPrice"
                            },
                            "batchDetails": {
                                "batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
                                "__typename": "SKUBatch"
                            },
                            "usageDate": {
                                "manufacture": "0000-00-00",
                                "expiry": "0000-00-00",
                                "__typename": "SKUUsage"
                            },
                            "updatedAt": "2019-11-05",
                            "active": true,
                            "__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
                        },
                        "Promotion": {
                            "id": null,
                            "title": null,
                            "type": null,
                            "scope": null,
                            "criteria": null,
                            "__typename": "Promotion"
                        },
                        "promotionId": null,
                        "distributorId": 16,
                        "__typename": "Line",
                        "inStock": "INSTOCK",
                        "freeSku": false,
                        "focusedSku": false
                    }
                ],
                "__typename": "PromotionOrder"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Request Body:

```json
{
    "operationName": null,
    "variables": {
        "input": {
            "invoiceId": 3683663,
            "orderDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 5105800,
                    "quantity": 200
                },
                {
                    "id": 5105801,
                    "quantity": 50
                },
                {
                    "id": 5105802,
                    "quantity": 40
                }
            ]
        },
        "type": "CatalogDetail"
    },
    "query": "mutation ($input: DispatchInput!) {\n dispatchInvoice(input: $input) {\n id\n __typename\n }\n}\n"
}
```

Comment: What do you use as programming language?

Comment: I am using Jmeter Json extractor for load test, not sure about programming language.

Answer (score 0):

When you use JavaScript, you could use the following one :)

```js
const responseBody = {
    "data": {
        "callOrders": [
            {
                "promotionId": null,
                "Promotion": null,
                "Lines": [
                    {
                        "id": 5105800,
                        "quantity": 200,
                        "skuId": 85,
                        "callId": 494281,
                        "skuBatchId": 587,
                        "amountDetails": {
                            "rate": 144.22,
                            "grossAmount": 32593.72,
                            "netAmount": 32593.72,
                            "taxAmount": 3749.72,
                            "taxableAmount": 28844,
                            "subTotal": 28844,
                            "billDiscount": 0,
                            "tradeDiscount": 0,
                            "discountAmount": 0,
                            "promotionDiscount": 0,
                            "topUpDiscount": 0,
                            "__typename": "AmountDetail"
                        },
                        "rateDetails": {
                            "rlp": 144.22,
                            "rlpWithVat": 162.9686,
                            "netPrice": 144.22,
                            "netPriceWithVat": 162.9686,
                            "__typename": "RateDetail"
                        },
                        "SKU": {
                            "id": 85,
                            "title": "Ariel Oxyblu 500 gm x 48 [82262305]",
                            "__typename": "SKU"
                        },
                        "SKUBatch": {
                            "priceDetails": {
                                "rlp": 144.22,
                                "dlp": 137.35,
                                "vatPercentage": 0.13,
                                "mrpSrp": 176,
                                "mrpStatus": true,
                                "__typename": "SKUPrice"
                            },
                            "batchDetails": {
                                "batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
                                "__typename": "SKUBatch"
                            },
                            "usageDate": {
                                "manufacture": "0000-00-00",
                                "expiry": "0000-00-00",
                                "__typename": "SKUUsage"
                            },
                            "updatedAt": "2018-12-01",
                            "active": true,
                            "__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
                        },
                        "Promotion": {
                            "id": null,
                            "title": null,
                            "type": null,
                            "scope": null,
                            "criteria": null,
                            "__typename": "Promotion"
                        },
                        "promotionId": null,
                        "distributorId": 16,
                        "__typename": "Line",
                        "inStock": "INSTOCK",
                        "freeSku": false,
                        "focusedSku": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5105801,
                        "quantity": 50,
                        "skuId": 82,
                        "callId": 494281,
                        "skuBatchId": 551,
                        "amountDetails": {
                            "rate": 281.88,
                            "grossAmount": 15926.22,
                            "netAmount": 15926.22,
                            "taxAmount": 1832.22,
                            "taxableAmount": 14094,
                            "subTotal": 14094,
                            "billDiscount": 0,
                            "tradeDiscount": 0,
                            "discountAmount": 0,
                            "promotionDiscount": 0,
                            "topUpDiscount": 0,
                            "__typename": "AmountDetail"
                        },
                        "rateDetails": {
                            "rlp": 281.88,
                            "rlpWithVat": 318.5244,
                            "netPrice": 281.88,
                            "netPriceWithVat": 318.5244,
                            "__typename": "RateDetail"
                        },
                        "SKU": {
                            "id": 82,
                            "title": "Ariel Oxyblu 1 kg x 24 [82250306]",
                            "__typename": "SKU"
                        },
                        "SKUBatch": {
                            "priceDetails": {
                                "rlp": 281.88,
                                "dlp": 268.45,
                                "vatPercentage": 0.13,
                                "mrpSrp": 344,
                                "mrpStatus": true,
                                "__typename": "SKUPrice"
                            },
                            "batchDetails": {
                                "batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
                                "__typename": "SKUBatch"
                            },
                            "usageDate": {
                                "manufacture": "0000-00-00",
                                "expiry": "0000-00-00",
                                "__typename": "SKUUsage"
                            },
                            "updatedAt": "2018-01-31",
                            "active": true,
                            "__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
                        },
                        "Promotion": {
                            "id": null,
                            "title": null,
                            "type": null,
                            "scope": null,
                            "criteria": null,
                            "__typename": "Promotion"
                        },
                        "promotionId": null,
                        "distributorId": 16,
                        "__typename": "Line",
                        "inStock": "INSTOCK",
                        "freeSku": false,
                        "focusedSku": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5105802,
                        "quantity": 40,
                        "skuId": 769,
                        "callId": 494281,
                        "skuBatchId": 733,
                        "amountDetails": {
                            "rate": 197.53,
                            "grossAmount": 8928.356,
                            "netAmount": 8928.356,
                            "taxAmount": 1027.156,
                            "taxableAmount": 7901.2,
                            "subTotal": 7901.2,
                            "billDiscount": 0,
                            "tradeDiscount": 0,
                            "discountAmount": 0,
                            "promotionDiscount": 0,
                            "topUpDiscount": 0,
                            "__typename": "AmountDetail"
                        },
                        "rateDetails": {
                            "rlp": 197.53,
                            "rlpWithVat": 223.2089,
                            "netPrice": 197.53,
                            "netPriceWithVat": 223.2089,
                            "__typename": "RateDetail"
                        },
                        "SKU": {
                            "id": 769,
                            "title": "H&S 2in1 Active Protect 180 ml x 24 [82302894]",
                            "__typename": "SKU"
                        },
                        "SKUBatch": {
                            "priceDetails": {
                                "rlp": 197.53,
                                "dlp": 186.35,
                                "vatPercentage": 0.13,
                                "mrpSrp": 250,
                                "mrpStatus": true,
                                "__typename": "SKUPrice"
                            },
                            "batchDetails": {
                                "batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
                                "__typename": "SKUBatch"
                            },
                            "usageDate": {
                                "manufacture": "0000-00-00",
                                "expiry": "0000-00-00",
                                "__typename": "SKUUsage"
                            },
                            "updatedAt": "2019-11-05",
                            "active": true,
                            "__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
                        },
                        "Promotion": {
                            "id": null,
                            "title": null,
                            "type": null,
                            "scope": null,
                            "criteria": null,
                            "__typename": "Promotion"
                        },
                        "promotionId": null,
                        "distributorId": 16,
                        "__typename": "Line",
                        "inStock": "INSTOCK",
                        "freeSku": false,
                        "focusedSku": false
                    }
                ],
                "__typename": "PromotionOrder"
            }
        ]
    }
};

const orderDetails = [];
responseBody.data.callOrders.forEach((entry) => {
    entry.Lines.forEach(({ id, quantity }) => {
        orderDetails.push({ id, quantity });
    })
});

const requestBody = {
    "operationName": null,
    "variables": {
        "input": {
            "invoiceId": 3683663,
            "orderDetails": orderDetails
        },
        "type": "CatalogDetail"
    },
    "query": "mutation ($input: DispatchInput!) {\n dispatchInvoice(input: $input) {\n id\n __typename\n }\n}\n"
};

console.log(requestBody);
```